# Coral Edge TPU connecting to windows 10

Tags: tpu, google-coral

I have setup Coral TPU successfully as described https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/. I could run the demo also. I did so using a Mac computer.

Now, I want to connect Coral to windows 10 machine. On Windows machine the drivers are installed along with mdt.

`mdt shell` returns:

```
Waiting for a device...
Unable to find any devices on your local network segment.
```

How can I connect?

Answer (score 1):

I think MDT tool doesn't support Windows 10 now.
You can connect via Serial Port and then enable SSH.
https://blog.questionable.services/article/coral-edge-tpu-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was originally asked, Google has released [official support for the Coral TPU on Windows](https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#on-windows).

The new `edgetpu_runtime` for Windows includes the drivers necessary for connecting to the Edge TPU on Windows without any of the need for working with `MDT`. Of note, when running inferences with the Edge TPU on Windows, it will register two USB disconnect/connect events. In the first one it is disconnecting the device so it can upload the model, and in the second it's moving it back to the normal mode to handle inferencing.